# Use nokogiri with xpath

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can i use nokogiri, to fetch image via xpath, but my main problem is that, i could have this div, but didn't have image:

```
image_node = @get_doc.xpath( '//*[@id="recaptcha_image"]/img/@src').map {|a| a.value }
    #binding.pry
    if image_node != nil
      rec = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( "#{image_node['src']}" ) ) 
    end
```

but i get

```
in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
```

how is it correct to use?

some part of html:

```
<div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display: none">
                                            <div id="recaptcha_image">
                                            <img *****>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field"
                                                style="width: 295px">
```

Comment: You're missing the HTML that should accompany the code, allowing us to test. You waste our time expecting us to create the HTML from scratch. In general I recommend using CSS selectors over XPath for normal stuff because CSS is much more readable. For instance, that search would be something like `search('#recaptcha_image > img > src')`

Comment: Check your attitude at the door. I didn't downvote you. I *might* vote to close you because you haven't met the basic requirements for a question: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance." But that won't occur until you've had a chance to fix the question.

Comment: @theTinMan i add part of html some time ago...

Comment: I started working on an answer some time ago, where "some time ago" is defined as 7 minutes, based on the timestamps.

Comment: One thing that isn't clear is whether the `<img>` tag would be missing, or, whether the tag exists, but it's missing the needed `src` attribute.

Comment: @theTinMan it could be missed in <div id="recaptcha_image">

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. What "it" do you mean? The `<img>` tag itself, or only the `src` parameter?

Comment: @theTinMan whole img tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend CSS over XPath for most HTML queries, and many XML ones. Using CSS makes this very "visible":

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display: none">
    <div id="recaptcha_image">
        <img src="path_to_image.jpg">
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" style="width: 295px">
EOT

doc.at('#recaptcha_widget img')['src'] # => "path_to_image.jpg"
```

---

> how to do check, if i have div, but didn't have image?

How do you check if you didn't have the embedded `<img>` tag inside the `<div>`? Break your lookup into two parts, and check for a `nil`:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display: none">
    <div id="recaptcha_image">
        <img src="path_to_image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="recaptcha_image2">
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" style="width: 295px">
EOT

img = doc.at('#recaptcha_widget img')
img_src = img['src'] # => "path_to_image.jpg"
```

If the `<img>` tag doesn't exist you'll get `nil`:

```
img = doc.at('#recaptcha_widget2 img') # => nil
```

From that point you'd continue with a check to see if `img` was set:

```
if (img)
  # ...do something...
end
```

Or, use a trailing `rescue` to capture the nil-exception and assign `nil` to `img_src` then test for it:

```
img_src = doc.at('#recaptcha_widget img')['src'] rescue nil # => "path_to_image.jpg"

img_src = doc.at('#recaptcha_widget2 img')['src'] rescue nil # => nil
if (img_src)
  # do something
end
```

Comment: but how to do check, if i have div, but didn't have image?  in my case it's not working

Comment: I added a solution to that. It's a case of incrementally moving through the DOM, and/or testing to see you have the previous information before trying to get the next/final information.